# Can I make files.useExperimentalFileWatcher *ask/warn* before refreshing a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VS Code and I noticed that files changed externally were not being noticed or picked up by VS Code.  Googled and found that the setting for it is files.useExperimentalFileWatcher = true.

I set that up and now changes are refreshed but there is no warning or even indication in VS Code that file was changed externally (and therefore refreshed.)

If I have some unsaved changes in VS Code and the file on disk is changed externally, VS Code neither refreshes (which is good, would lose edits) nor warns (which is bad - you could lose what was changed externally.)

There seems to be no way to force Code to refresh or otherwise deal with the issue.  This SO question ([Visual Studio Code: Auto-refresh file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078077/visual-studio-code-auto-refresh-file-changes)) seems to imply that some diff type window/dialog opens but I don't see that.

Is there a setting for this or is this a bug?.

Currently on v1.25.1, W10 x64

Answer (score -1):

I'm using 1.26.1 on Windows 10, and though I can't get `files.useExperimentalFileWatcher = true` to do anything, I do get a notification in the lower-right corner: if I start editing a file and in the meanwhile it is modified by another program, there's no warning  at first, but when I try to save it I get this popup:

[image: VS Code Failed to save please compare]

And by clicking on Compare I get to this screen:

[image: VS Code Compare files]

Notice the buttons on the right to accept or discard the change.

If you don't get this option, it's likely a bug. Try updating to the latest version, it's possible it's already been solved.

Comment: So you only get a warning if/when you try to save the file over an external edit?  That's an odd behavior.  I mean, better than clobbering but a little too late to be actually useful.  Especially if I'd want to view the changed file or monitor for changes.   What I expect is the same behavior of most editors I've encountered (pop up as soon as a file changes (and VSC is in focus.)  NPP, Atom, Eclipse for example behave that way.) It's odd imo (and less useful) for VSC not to do it the same.

Comment: I completely agree with you, that's why I left [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078077/visual-studio-code-auto-refresh-file-changes/30083688#comment91186367_30083688) under the accepted answer to the same question that you linked to, asking whether anyone has already opened an issue. Let's see...

Comment: Upvoted both your comments.  Also @warrenp (2nd comment in first answer) saying same thing