# How to make VSCode to forcefully reload a changed file?

Tags: git, file, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue with VSCode where it does not want to load changed file due to checking out a different branch. I do not care what VSCode thinks about the current file, I would like it to reload if a file changed on the disk or even better, it recognizes that the branch has changed and it reloads the file.

I can see that it may want to keep the file if the file has some unsaved changes, but that is not what I care. I would like it to reload it given that I am changing a branch on the file system.

I do not know what this feature might be called, but the only way I found was to revert the file, although I am not reverting it.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/186976#issue-1787728566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the (experimental) file watcher. There must be some bugs maybe, but you can well do Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> File -> Check Experimental File watcher. Also, dont forget to ignore files where you don't need this to happen.(As Reactjs-node_modules, for example)

Comment: Ok thanks, sounds like this can be a potential solution. I will post my impressions for it later

Comment: Per https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74630#issue-450432162, doesn't this not exist anymore?

Answer (score 30):

If you prefer a one-time manual action, you can use `File -> Revert` (or CTRL+SHIFT+P revert file).

Answer (score -2):

Copy the file to a folder outside the project.
Delete the file using VisualStudioCode
Exit VS code
Copy the file back