# How to force VSCode to reload a modifyed file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I did some mistakes when changing a code file, but I didn't save it, and I wanted to reload the previous version from the disk...

But I don't found how to reload the file **without exiting it** from the editor...
It is possible to have a basic option, like in "notepad++", to reload easily a file with the last unsaved copy ?

Comment: Are you not able to undo changes with `Ctrl+Z`?

Comment: no, too many changes...

Comment: Ok, why is there a constraint of not closing the file from editor?

Comment: No, I did it finally... But it's for the next time: I'm surprised I haven't found such a basic option. There are so many options that I don't know in this environment, but I'm sure it must be in.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761414/7867822

Comment: If https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/186976#issue-1787728566 is upvoted 20 times, this will become possible because the feature will be moved to VSCode's backlog.

Answer (score 1):

You can reload VS code at ant time by just pressing

```
Ctrl + Shift + P
```

By doing this , vs code will pool recent and updated files And folders

Answer (score 0):

You can reload by holding down CTRL + SHIFT + P and then typing "Reload Window".